# PHP Array convert to be double quote

Tags: php, arrays

How to give double quote every comma

```
$var = array();
$var[] = "a, b, c";
$var = explode( ',', $var );
```

What I want to display is:

```
var[] = ("a", "b", "c");
```

Comment: You may looking for `implode()` instead of `explode()`?

Comment: explode() method expects second param to be string rather then array which you are giving it?

Comment: is it an interview qestion?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave What is the status of this question?  Does amenadiel's solution solve your issue or do you require a different answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string

```
$mystring="a, b, c";
```

That you explode into an array

```
$myarray = explode(', ', $mystring);
```

Your array will have three elements, and each of them is a string, so it's true that

```
$myarray == ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

While it is also true that

```
$myarray == ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Now, if you want your array to store string **specifically including the double quotes**, to have

```
$myarray == ['"a"', '"b"', '"c"'];
```

That would need you to perform an `array_map`, but it seems outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave This seems like a correct answer, though your answer isn't super clear.  Please move your question toward a resolution by either marking this answer as accepted, or providing feedback with a comment or question edit (and then pinging amenadiel).

Comment: @HiDayurieDave I see that you have logged in to SO.  Please resolve this question by marking an accepted answer.  This seems like the right one.

Answer (score -1):

(sorry for bad english)

```
$var = array(); //you declare $var as array
$var[] = "a, b, c"; // you assign $var[0] = "a, b, c"
$var = explode( ',', $var ); // call explode with $var which is an array and will give error because second param must be a string
```

when you put `[]` at the end of a variable (like `$var[]`) you are telling php that `$var` is an array

when you assing a value like you do (`$var[] = "a, b, c"`) you are telling php to store that string using the fisrt available slot/space inside that array, in this case is zero (`0`).

if you want to store that string as array using `,` as separator, you simply do:

```
$var = explode(",", "a, b, c");
```

Comment: explode on comma&space to keep it all neat.  your solution does not return the expected result.